# Is it possible to decrease latency between button press and event handling?

Tags: python, kivy, latency

I am trying to build a drum machine-like project in Kivy/Python. I have been able to set up some of the main functionality, but there is too much latency between when I actually press the button and when the sound plays (almost unplayable). Is it possible to decrease this latency until it is nearly instantaneous?

I have the code to get keypresses because I want the app to be usable from the keyboard as well as on touchscreen devices.

I've already tried paring down my code and running `sound.play()` directly (in case dictionary lookups were adding noticeable latency), but for me it's still not enough.

firstapp.py

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.7')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

samples = {
    "1"  : "kick.wav",
        "2"  : "hat1.wav",
        "3"  : "hat2.wav",
        "4"  : "snare.wav",
        "A"  : None,

        "5"  : "gunshot.wav" # ...etc

}

sounds = {}

kitPath = "kit/"

class GridLayoutApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GridLayoutApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # create keypress event listeners
        Window.bind(on_key_up=self._keyup)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._keydown)
        # self.trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.cb1)

        self.sounds = {}
        # Load sounds
        for key, value in samples.items():
            if value != None:
                self.sounds[key] = SoundLoader.load(kitPath + value)

        self.gunshot = SoundLoader.load(kitPath + "gunshot.wav")


    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('gridlayout.kv')

    def _keydown(self, *args):
        k = args[3]
        if k == '1':
            self.root.ids.b1.state = 'down'
            self.root.ids.b1.trigger_action(0)
        if k == '2':
            self.root.ids.b2.state = 'down'
            self.root.ids.b2.trigger_action(0)
        if k == '3':
            self.root.ids.b3.state = 'down'
            self.root.ids.b3.trigger_action(0)
        if k == '4':
            self.root.ids.b4.state = 'down'
            self.root.ids.b4.trigger_action(0)
        if k == '5':
            self.root.ids.b5.state = 'down'
            self.root.ids.b5.trigger_action(0)

    def _keyup(self, *args):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GridLayoutApp().run()
```

gridlayout.kv

```py
#:kivy 1.0
#:import SoundLoader kivy.core.audio

GridLayout:
    cols: 5
    Button:
        id: b1
        text: '1'
        #on_state: app.stateHandler(b1)
        on_press: app.sounds['1'].play()
    Button:
        id: b2
        text: '2'
        on_press: app.sounds['2'].play()
    Button:
        id: b3
        text: '3'
        on_press: app.sounds['3'].play()
    Button:
        id: b4
        text: '4'
        on_press: app.sounds['4'].play()
    Button:
        text: 'A'
        on_press:


    Button:
        id: b5
        text: '5'
        on_press: app.gunshot.play() # calling play() directly
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very unlikely that you'll be able to get musically meaningful latency with this sort of architecture. For that kind of timing, you usually need to use lower-level sound APIs at the very least, and possibly (I'm not familiar with Kivy's innards) a UI framework that has lower latency itself.

Comment: You could try forcing the `Sound` object to load in your `__init__`. (See [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html#kivy.core.audio.Sound.load)). That might help...

Comment: There are frameworks intended specifically for live performances; you're going to have an easier time starting somewhere the upstream maintainers are themselves thinking about your use case (or, better, performing themselves!). [Overtone](https://overtone.github.io/) or another [SuperCollider](https://supercollider.github.io/)-based framework would be a solid place to start